# Clojure macro: Create local vars from a map

Tags: clojure

I have this sample code where I create vars by iterating over the key value pair of the map.

```
(defmacro block [bindings & body] 
  `(let [
    ~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [(if (symbol? k) k (symbol (name k))) `~v]) bindings) ]
  ~body))

(block {:a 1 :b 2} (if true (prn "true" a b) (prn "false")))
```

It works fine.
Ouput: "true" 1 2

---

But now I want to pass the same map as a var but, it thows an exception.

IllegalArgumentException Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol

```
(def ctx {:a 3 :b 4})

(block ctx (if true (prn "true" a b) (prn "false")))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work, when you pass a symbol that refers to a var that holds a map, is because the macro is only seeing the symbol literal — not the value it refers to. When you pass it a map literal, the macro is seeing the map literal.

If you wanted it to also support symbols, you'll need to `resolve` the var the symbol refers to and get its value e.g. `(var-get (resolve bindings))`:

```
(defmacro block [bindings & body]
  `(let [~@(mapcat (fn [[k v]] [(if (symbol? k)
                                  k
                                  (symbol (name k))) `~v])
                   (cond
                     (map? bindings) bindings
                     (symbol? bindings) (var-get (resolve bindings))
                     :else (throw (Exception. "bindings must be map or symbol"))))]
     ~@body))

(block ctx (if true (prn "true" a b) (prn "false")))
"true" 3 4
(block {:a 3 :b 4} (if true (prn "true" a b) (prn "false")))
"true" 3 4
```

You also need to "splice" `body` into the form using `~@`, because `body` will be a sequence of forms even if it only contains one form.

It can also help to look at how your macro expands when troubleshooting it:

```
(macroexpand-1 '(block ctx (if true (prn "true" a b) (prn "false"))))
=> (clojure.core/let [a 3 b 4] (if true (prn "true" a b) (prn "false")))
```

Comment: What happens when you want to use this in a func

Comment: @JAtkin macros behave the same way in functions as they do everywhere else — they get "expanded" before the code that calls them is evaluated.

Comment: This throws a NullPointerException for me when I pass a variable.